# Передача данных из окна диалога в окно вида по нажатию Ok

Tags: mfc, c++

У меня есть структура в документе MyAppDoc.h:

```
struct StudInfo
{
public:
    CString f;     //фамилия
}
```

Мне нужно, чтобы по нажатию на кнопку, введенные данные записывались в структуру `StudInfo`:

```
  void MODELESS::OnBnClickedButton3()
{
    StudInfo s;
    MyControl dlg2;
    s.f = dlg2.m_familiya;
    if (dlg2.DoModal() == IDOK);
    ;// update current record
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нужно поменять строки местами

```
void MODELESS::OnBnClickedButton3()
{
    StudInfo s;
    MyControl dlg2;

    if (dlg2.DoModal() == IDOK)
      s.f = dlg2.m_familiya; // update current record
}
```

И в dlg2, в обработчике кнопки Ok, сделать UpdateData, чтобы в переменную "m_familiya" записалась строка из поля ввода.

Comment: в эту переменную записывается только значение по умолчанию, а UpdateData() не работает

Comment: m_familiya связана с строкой ввода? Что возвращает UpdateData?

Comment: а что должно возвращать? m_familiya связана

Comment: После updatedate в переменную m_familiya должн быть помещен текст из editbox'a, с которым эта переменная связана.